# Passing an NSManagedObjectContext to a tableview when its embedded in navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uinavigationcontroller

I'm creating an application with a few TableViews and i have the first screen which is a normal view, im creating in the AppDelegate a `NSManagedObjectContext` and I was passing it to other views using this for example:

```
PickTypeViewController *controller = (PickTypeViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

But now I embedded my tableview in a navigation controller (Editor-emmbed in -navigation controller) and I want to transfer the `NSManagedObjectContext` to my tableview but I dont know how to send it through the navigation controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table view controller will be the topViewController of the navigation controller, so you can do it like this:

```
UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;
MyTableViewController *tvc = nav.topViewController;
tvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```